# Can i use a discriminator in an association mapper?

Tags: java, mybatis

I  want to set a result property depending on a concrete state of an Object (State Pattern).

How can I do this best with myBatis?

This approach gives me an error:

```
<association property="state" javaType="commonInterface">
    <discriminator javaType="String" column="state">
        <case value="CREATED" resultType="ClassA" />
        <case value="RUNNING" resultType="ClassB" />
        <case value="FINSHED" resultType="ClassC" />
    </discriminator>
</association>
```

The error is:

```
Could not set property 'state' of 'FatherClass' with value '1' 
Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.example.State field 
com.example.state to java.lang.Long
```

So somehow myBatis returns an Long instead of a concrete object. Is this approach possible at all?

edit: The Status "CREATED", "RUNNING", "FINISHED" comes from an enum, when it is saved to the database. But when it is read again I can easily treat it as a String - right?!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably declare your POJO as enum instead of class, anyway, there is a default enum handling in Mybatis but you can go ahead and provide your own custom handler:

read more about it at: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers